# Blogging with CakePhp

Tags: cakephp, blogs

I have a cakePhp application built, and now I'm creating a simple blog based on our activities (much like blog.stackoverflow.com).

What blogging plugins / software are most commonly used with CakePhp?  Wordpress? lilblogs?

Just a few pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Why dont you use a stand-alone Wordpress installation/account for your blogging needs? Is there a specific requirement that forces you to use your own CakePHP application for blogging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Wordpress, then if you want create CakePHP models which map to the Wordpress tables, then bake out the controllers etc if you really wanted to. I've done this a few times, as an easy way to get CakePHP to render recent wordpress articles.

Have a read about Models in the book, which will tell you how to build a custom model. http://book.cakephp.org/view/66/Models

Comment: I've done this and it works very well. I've even created a plugin to access the WP data. up vote earned.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of applications specific to cakephp but you really should know about the resources that are available for free when you get into this venture.

Try these [10 Essential Blogging Tools for Every Blogger Should Use.](http://techchai.com/2011/04/17/10-essential-blogging-tools-for-every-blogger-should-use/)